# How can I reverse screen image in UBUNTU14.04 used on NVIDIA Jestson TK1?

Tags: 14.04, nvidia, hdmi

I want to use the LCD monitor (multi-touch), connected via HDMI on *NVIDIA Jetson TK1*, in two positions: a) first: the monitor in horizontal position (on the table for calligraphic handwriting); b) second: the monitor in vertical position like on any laptop, and for that I need to reverse the image on the desktop. My embedded system is made similar with an laptop/notebook. Is it a possibility to do that in software (Ubuntu 14.04) or need to use an accelerometer? Thank you very much for your help. With best regards, Ion